# Make react child component to occupy full screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, components, react-native-camera

Maybe I missed something after going through react native camera docs. I want to create a component that will launch RNC full screen. My challenge is creating a child component that will hold the full screen view of the camera. I currently have the child component having flex 1 but it's not working as expected.

Comment: can you share an expo snack link so that we can check?

Comment: What about adding position: absolute, left: 0, right: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0 ??